# Excel - Check cells for duplicate value, that it starts with a letter across worksheets

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have 2 worksheets, **SheetA** & **SheetB** I'm checking cells to ensure there is no duplication within column B and that the value entered starts with a letter. The following formula works fine when applied to a cell in column B on either sheet.

```
=AND(CODE(LEFT(B10,1))>=56,CODE(LEFT(B10,1))<=122,COUNTIF($B:$B,B10)=1)
```

I get a warning if the cell matches a value anywhere in column B or if the first character is a not letter.

I want to expand this so the duplication check looks at column B on worksheets A & B.

I've changed the formula to

```
=AND(CODE(LEFT(B10,1))>=56,CODE(LEFT(B10,1))<=122,COUNTIF(SheetA!$B:$B,B10,SheetB!$B:$B,B10)=1)
```

But that throws an error and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Can anyone advice how to write a formula that can be applied to all cells in column B on workseets A & B that checks for duplication across these two columns and ensures the value starts with a letter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=AND(CODE(LEFT(B10,1))>=56,CODE(LEFT(B10,1))<=122,COUNTIF(SheetA!$B:$B,B10)+COUNTIF(SheetB!$B:$B,B10)=1)
```

Comment: thanks that seems to work, but I had to swap the sheet names around when applied to SheetB